# How can I fetch m4a aac metadata using batch?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, audio

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is writing a script to rename the files in my song library to the following format

"song name - artist"

I have tried looking for code that would fetch that data from those files but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got this line of code from:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/226773/how-to-read-mp3-tags-in-shell

Specifically, user mxmlnkn gave the right answer. I used their code to achieve something similar to what your are looking for and it works fine:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=artist -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 file.mp3
```

And if you want to add, for example, album and name of the track, you then use the `format_tags` as follows:

```
format_tags=artist,album,title
```